# pass an image through a router in expressJs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an express application and i want to pass an image through a router as a response (line in js is the one with message: ...). How do i do that since it returns it as a string?

```js
router.post('/authorization_cub', function (request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;
  if (username && password) {
    dbconnection.query('SELECT * FROM confidential WHERE branch = ? AND passphrase = ?', [username, password], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (results.length > 0) {
        request.session.loggedin = true;
        request.session.username = username;
        response.redirect('/confidential/cubs');
      } else {
        response.render('confidential/cubs_login', {
          message: '<img src="images/confidential/tongue_face.gif" alt="φάτσα με γλώσσα"></img>'
        });
      }
      response.end();
    });
  } else {
    response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
    response.end();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="login-form">
        <h2>Βάλε το σωστό σύνθημα:</h2>
        <form action="authorization_cub" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="username" value="Λυκόπουλα">
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Βάλε το σύνθημά σου εδώ" required>
          <input type="submit" value="Είσοδος">
          <%=message%>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always make a separation of concerns :

```
response.render('confidential/cubs_login', {
          img: 'images/confidential/tongue_face.gif'
        })
```

...
// in your template

```
<img src="<%= img %>"/>
```